# How do I get rid of an outfit?

Tags: hamtaro-ham-ham-heartbreak

I want to purchase a red spacesuit in Hamtaro: Ham-Ham Heartbreak. However, I've hit the limit of how many outfits I can have. Is there a way to get rid of an outfit or increase the number of outfits I can carry?

[image: Hitting the 30 outfit maximum]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of an outfit

- Go to the Clubhouse
- Enter the photo room and start the dress up minigame.
- Select Menu > Toss
- Choose an item to get rid of.

[image: toss menu]
[image: tossing an item]

Note: You can access the dress up minigame from either the clubhouse or the title screen.